# Shortcut to run a project in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm working on a large Silverlight solution with 75+ projects.  Instead of right clicking on the start up project and then selecting Debug | Start New Instance...   I'd like to use a keyboard shortcut to run this specific project.  Hitting F5 is a non-starter, even if I select the option to only build the start up project and it's dependencies. Takes too long.

Accomplishing this was easy with the macro functionality in VS 2010.  I haven't been able to find a good way to replace this capability in VS2102.  Note, I have tried the Visual Commander extension but it doesn't seem to be able to automate this kind of command sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can't record it automatically, you can just paste this code as a VB command in Visual Commander with your project name:

```
DTE.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindSolutionExplorer).Activate()
DTE.ActiveWindow.Object.GetItem("MySolution\MyProject").Select(vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeSelect)
DTE.ExecuteCommand("ClassViewContextMenus.ClassViewProject.Debug.Startnewinstance")
```